# VF Page need to be call after record Save

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a scenario as follows :
     Agreement records are created from external system. On the Detail page of the 'Agreement' we do have one button called 'Submit Request'. User has to click on this Button manually which in turn calls the other vf page.
    We need to automate this as follows:
 As soon as the Agreement created from external system this VF Page needs to be called automatically. Can you guys please help me out.

Comment: Why do you need to automate a process of calling a VF page? What is your use case here?

Comment: We have Apttus enabled in the system. On the Detail page we have ' Submit Request' Button. On click on this we are navigating to Apttus vf page which in turn generates the Agreement documents for that record and sent email. We need to generate this document and mail notification to be done on record creation it self. As it is a managed package apex class i am not able to access it directly from out side of its managed package components.

Comment: You cannot just navigate to a VF page on a record creation. Remember, VF page is just a UI component of the framework. You will need to have access to the underlying controller that the page works upon to be able to create the necessary records that you want.

Comment: Yes agree. But it is a manage package apex class. Is there anyway to access it from unmanaged apex. ?

Comment: You will need to reach out to the package provider.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

> On the Detail page we have ' Submit Request' Button. On click on this we are navigating to Apttus vf page which in turn generates the Agreement documents for that record and sent email. We need to generate this document and mail notification to be done on record creation it self.

VF page is the UI component of the Visualforce framework. There's no real cause of navigating to a VF page once a record has been created. You **cannot** navigate to a VF page whenever a record is created (not taking into account a UI flow here).

What you need here is to create the underlying records which when a User would navigate to the VF page, and then upon submission of the page, would create those records. You will instead need to invoke the VF page's *underlying controller logic* from the trigger of your record creation.

If you are dealing with a managed package, then you will need to reach out to the package provider to get details as how you can utilize the same logic in your flow. Most of the package providers provide a way either by exposing API, or by letting you write trigger on their objects so that you can address these type of scenarios. So your solution here is to reach out to the package provider to get more details as how you can address this.